# SSH connection dropping quickly on CENTOS vs UBUNTU. Wrong ssh config?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos

I have a script running locally on Ubuntu and I want to put that on a CentOs docker container.

Both scripts contain the same `ssh credentials` and settings, yet when I launch the container the script, the container seems to log in and drop the connection right away. From the logs I can't understand why, is there maybe weird `ssh` default on CentOs that makes the connection drop like that?

The command is as follows

```bash
sshpass -p CrazyPassword# \ 
ssh -vvv -J awsvpn admin@10.2.3.224 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa \ 
    -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 \ 
    -L 1234:192.168.1.1:80 -L 8080:192.168.1.1:8080 -L 1235:192.168.1.100:80 \ 
    -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -tt
```

The verbose log from my machine is (removed the initial part as that is identical)

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to 10.2.3.224 (via proxy) using "password".
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1234 forwarded to remote address 192.168.1.1:80
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1234.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 3 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1234.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8080 forwarded to remote address 192.168.1.1:8080
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 7 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8080.
bind [::1]:8080: Address already in use
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
bind [127.0.0.1]:8080: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1235 forwarded to remote address 192.168.1.100:80
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 7 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1235.
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1235.
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 3: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 4: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 4
debug2: channel 4: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 4: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 4
debug2: channel 4: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
..skipping env ...
*************** here the SSH seems to work and the connection stays open ****************
debug2: channel 4: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 4: callback done
debug2: channel 4: open confirm rwindow 24576 rmax 32759
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 4
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 4
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 4
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 4
```

while on the CentOs container the following happens

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.2.3.224 (via proxy).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1234 forwarded to remote address 192.168.1.1:80
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1234.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 3 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 6 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1234.
bind: Cannot assign requested address
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8080 forwarded to remote address 192.168.1.1:8080
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
bind: Address already in use
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 6 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8080.
bind: Cannot assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1235 forwarded to remote address 192.168.1.100:80
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1235.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 7 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1235.
bind: Cannot assign requested address
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 2
debug2: channel 2: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: proc
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2
debug2: channel 2: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: tty_make_modes: no fd or tio
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 2: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
*************** here the SSH seems to connect BUT the connection drops immediately ****************
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 24576 rmax 32759
debug2: channel 2: read<=0 rfd 7 len 0
debug2: channel 2: read failed
debug2: channel 2: close_read
debug2: channel 2: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 2: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 2: input drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 2
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 2
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: obuf empty
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 2: rcvd close
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 2: almost dead
debug2: channel 2: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 2: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 2: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:

debug1: channel 1: free: port listener, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 10.2.3.224 closed.
Transferred: sent 2216, received 1504 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8560.7, received 5810.2
debug1: Exit status 0
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for 10.2.3.224 port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for 10.2.3.224 port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536 (t4 r0 i1/0 o0/0 fd -1/5 cc -1)

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 2 is not O_NONBLOCK
```

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: The might be something in the remote user's shell startup files (.bash_profile etc) that causes the user's shell to exit right away. Or the user's shell might be set to something like /bin/false or some program that is malfunctioning.

Comment: thanks a lot, is there a list of the possible files to check that can affect ssh connection? I thought they were all contained in .ssh